# android application for customer end user and vendor end user

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to developing android mobile applications. I am trying to build an application using android studio, api level 23.

I have two types of users, customers and admins.
My project is a food ordering application in a campus.
A user can order food from different restaurants located in the campus. An admin user ( for each restaurant) can actually update the menu like he can remove (disable) an item from the existing items list so that the customers cant see it the menu after he does that.
So, what all I need to do to implement this application. I mean what are the api's required for me to do , Can I just use the android studio, does everything what I have to do can  be done using that IDE or Do I need anything else like api's or different cloud databases or just I can do it with the client-server architecture or How do I start?

Comment: Use android studio for app development and create webservices in php....and call that api's in app...thats it.

Comment: You should first list all your requirements for the app. Then, start building your app step by step. Then, search for how to achieve the specific functionality on this site and if not found here, put up a question. Yes, android studio is all that you need for app development. For backend, it's your choice actually.

Comment: So can I create mobile application for the vendor user also just by updating the tables, does it reflect in the customer side?

Comment: I want to know about the backend, that's why I posted this question, what all iptions I have ?